# Oracle ROWNUM pagination numbering problem

Tags: sql, oracle

I have some problem sorting columns and paginate them.

for example,

```
select *
from
    (select A.*, ROWNUM RNUM
         from 
        (select * from USER order by name) A
        where ROWNUM <= 3 --edited
    ) B
    where RNUM >= 1
```

as A

and

```
select *
from
    (select A.*, ROWNUM RNUM
         from 
        (select * from USER order by name) A
        where ROWNUM <= 4 --edited
    ) B
    where RNUM >= 1
```

as B

The difference of two is columns rownums.
I want to know why this happened.

---

A returns,

```
RNUM | NAME
-----------
1    | a
-----------
2    | b
-----------
3    | c
```

B returns.

```
RNUM | NAME
-----------
1    | a
-----------
2    | f     -- what happened?
-----------
3    | b
-----------
4    | c
```

This is just an example.

Why each columns gets different rownums because of range of rownum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why *what* happened?

- source is `select * from user` (apparently, false table name; that's reserved for function that returns username of a currently logged *user*) so it selects *all rows* from the table
- `rownum rnum` then reflects number of all rows returned from that table, one-by-one, from 1 to total number of rows in that table
- `where rownum <= 10` restricts number of rows returned by the source subquery to 10 (the 1st example) / 200 (the 2nd example). It means that

  - the 1st query works with at most 10 rows
  - the 2nd query works with at most 200 rows
- the final filter (`where rnum >= 1`) returns what's previously being said - at most 10 (or 200) rows

So ... what's the problem? What did you expect to get?

---

As of your comment: it seems that `order by` clause is missing:

```
select *
from
    (select A.*, ROWNUM RNUM
         from 
        (select * from USER order by name) A
        where ROWNUM <= 10
        order by a.name                 --> this
    ) B
    where RNUM >= 1
```

Comment: thank you. i updated my question, so maybe this will help you to answer my question?

Comment: Aha; it seems that you're missing ORDER BY. Have a look at edited answer, modify your queries and try again.

Comment: Hello. I misunderstand my problem. I updated my question. can you read the question again? thank you.

Comment: Hello. I solved problem. There was a sorting problem with duplicated values. thank you.

Comment: OK; I'm glad you made it, you're welcome.